# pandas series row-wise comparison (preserve cardinality/indices of larger series)

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas series, both string dtypes.

1. reports['corpus'] has 1287 rows

   0    point seem peaking effects drug unique compari...

   1    mother god seen much difficult withstand spent...

   2    getting weird half breakthrough feels like sec...

   3    vomited three times bucket suddenly felt much ...

   4    reached peak mild walk around without difficul...
2. labels['uniq_labels'] has 52 rows

   0           amplification

   1             enhancement

   2             psychedelic

   3                 sensory

   4                  visual

I want to create a new series object equal to the size of reports['corpus']. In it, each row needs to contain a list of string matches (i.e. searching reports['corpus'] for exact string matches to strings in labels['uniq_labels']).

I have tried looping over the two series to check if a string from labels['uniq_labels'] is in a report from reports['corpus']. I split at the report iter and am able to return a list of the strings that match. Though I can't seem to preserve conditions such as: allocating string matches for a given report to the reports' index position (very important).

Edit (Adding example of the series objects):

```
reports_series = pd.Series(['This is a test first sentence. \
                            This is the first row of a pandas series.',
                            'Here is the second row. The row that means the most. The row that never goes away.',
                            'The third sentence. The third row to the example pandas series.',
                            'This is the fourth and only fourth row of the pandas series.',
                            'Here is the fifth row. The fifth row that means the most.'])

labels_series = pd.Series(['first', 'sentence', 'second row'])
```

Comment: please provide your data as text that can be easily copy/pasted to form a dataframe

Comment: @mozway I don't have the permission to provide the exact data but I can produce an example for you.

Comment: @mozway please refer to the edit in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert `uniq_labels` column from the `labels` dataframe to a list, and split the `corpus` column from `reports` dataframe on white space, and take the values that are in both the lists.

```py
(reports['corpus']
.str.split(' ')
.apply(lambda x:[i for i in labels['uniq_labels'].tolist() if i in x]))
0    []
1    []
2    []
3    []
4    []
Name: corpus, dtype: object
```

In the sample you have mentioned above, no values actually match, so the output has empty list only.

Comment: this works beautifully. This is the accepted answer. Thank you for your help